# How can I pass size argument to sns.FacetGrid.map()?

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to draw a scatter plot using a pandas dataframe using CIACountries.csv

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.read_csv("CIACountries.csv")


grid = sns.FacetGrid(data, col="net_users")
grid.map(sns.scatterplot, "educ", "gdp", "roadways")
plt.yscale("log", basey=10)
```

The "roadways" column is currently used as the hue argument
I want the column "roadways" to represent the size of the dots in the scatterplot.
Is there a way I can do this?

I tried putting another "roadways" argument but it raises an error as it in put in the 'styles' argument

```
grid.map(sns.scatterplot, "educ", "gdp", "roadways", "roadways")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.map_dataframe` and add a `hue=` and `size=` parameter. The following code uses seaborn's tips dataset for easy reproducibility.  Note that `size=` means the `size` parameter of `sns.scatterplot`, while `"size"` is here the "size" column of the tips dataset (i.e. the table size).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col='day')
g.map_dataframe(sns.scatterplot, 'total_bill', 'tip', hue='sex', size='size')
g.add_legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.FacetGrid with scatterplot and size parameter]

Note that, in general, it is recommended to avoid directly calling `sns.FacetGrid`. Instead, you could call the corresponding figure-level function. `sns.relplot` creates a `FacetGrid` of scatter plots (and automatically adds a legend).

```py
g = sns.relplot(tips, col='day', x='total_bill', y='tip', hue='sex', size='size')
```